# How to connect Android on external host (not localhost)

Tags: android, authentication, host

I decided to connect to an external host my app but don't work. How can i do? 
this is an exemple:

```
  String login_url = "http://***.**.**.**/fileman/**/register.php";
   // String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2/code/register.php";

    String method = params[0];

    if (method.equals("register")) {


        String name = params[1];
        String user_name = params[2];
        String user_pass = params[3];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            //httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("user_pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_pass, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            OS.close();
            InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();
            //httpURLConnection.connect();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();


           ritorno = "Registration Success...";
            return ritorno;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

with localhost work, but when i use my url don't work.. (if i use my url on google adress he work)

what is wrong?

Comment: Did u get any error

Comment: Nothing, he don't do nothing.. I need to click button, when i click he don't do nothing

Comment: didi u add intenet permision in manifest

Comment: I think the problem is how to write the url

Comment: yes i add becouse if i use localhost url he work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you supposed to be using `login_url` rather than `reg_url` in `URL url = new URL(reg_url)`? I think `reg_url` was initialized with something else.

Comment: omg, error of distraction. Tnks lot of :D I can't give u point because I haven't 15 rep D: